# Number of steps of Euclidean algorithm. why $r_i{_+}_2 < \frac{1}{2}r_i$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

I'm reading "Friendly Introduction to Number Theory". Now I'm working on Number of steps of Euclidean algorithm Exercises 5.3 on P35.

> 5.3. Let b = r0, r1, r2, . . . be the successive remainders in the Euclidean algorithm applied
>   to a and b. Show that after every two steps, the remainder is reduced by at least one half.
>   In other words, verify that

$r_i{_+}_2 < \frac{1}{2}r_i$ for every i = 0, 1, 2, . . . .

https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/frintch1ch6.pdf

I confirmed the above equation worked. But I don't understand where $1/2$ came from? Can you give me a hint?

$22x + 60y = gcd(22, 60)$

$60 = 2 * 22 + 16$

$22 = 1 * 16 + 6$

$16 = 2 * 6 + 4$

$6 = 1 * 4 + 2$

$4 = 2 * 2 + 0$

---

Update 1

@lhf gave me the comment but I can't understand the step (5). Why 2$r_{i+2}$ ?

(1) $r_i = r_{i+1} q_{i+2} + r_{i+2}$

(2) with $r_{i+2} < r_{i+1}$.

(3) Since $r_{i+1} < r_{i}$, we have $q_{i+2} \ge 1$,

(4) and so $r_i = r_{i+1} q_{i+2} + r_{i+2} \ge r_{i+1} + r_{i+2}$.

(5) $r_{i+1} + r_{i+2} > 2r_{i+2}$

//

$22x + 60y = gcd(22, 60)$ // a=60, b=22

$60 = 2 * 22 + 16$ // $a = 2*b + r_i$

$22 = 1 * 16 + 6$ // $b = 1*r_i + r_i{_+}_1$

$16 = 2 * 6 + 4$ // $r_i = 2*r_i{_+}_1 + r_i{_+}_2$

$6 = 1 * 4 + 2$

$4 = 2 * 2 + 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$
r_i = r_{i+1} q_{i+2} + r_{i+2}
$
with $r_{i+2} < r_{i+1}$.

Since $r_{i+1} < r_{i}$, we have $q_{i+2} \ge 1$, and so
$
r_i = r_{i+1} q_{i+2} + r_{i+2} \ge r_{i+1} + r_{i+2} > 2r_{i+2} 
$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me some time to think about it?

Comment: Sorry.. still not sure the last part why $r_{i+1} + r_{i+2} > 2r_{i+2}$?

Comment: @zono, because $r_{i+1} > r_{i+2}$.

Comment: I got it finally. Thank you so much.